# Javascript car movement in x axis from accelerometer data?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, accelerometer

I have X, Y and Z-axis data from an accelerometer sensor. I want to use the accelero(X) data to visualize a car in 2D.
This is how the data look like.

[image]

This is a sample of the data:

[image]

The link for the full data is below:

[Click here to download the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ww2Knot5eppUKVhRbOdktO0zpdV-3G9/view)

The car model looks like that in 2D space:

[image]

The car only move up or down according to the input data from the file.

I tried to lookup [Three.Js](https://threejs.org/), [Phaser.Js](https://phaser.io/), [Planck.Js](https://piqnt.com/planck.js/), [Matter.Js](https://brm.io/matter-js/), Phyics.Js and other gaming engines.
But I am looking for something really simple as a starting point without the need to use fancy gravity, physics functions, but at the same time the model should be convincing and smooth.

So can someone direct in the right path? How to do it? which library is best to perform this task? Is there an already implemented code that I use and modify according to my need?

I have been working on some code using the aformentioned libraries, for that reason, I didn't post the code here, as I am looking for an easier and simpler solution.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an exemple (in 3D) using accelerometer and Arduino code on my github here :
https://github.com/BaptisteZloch/Tracking-orientation-with-P5.js

I have used p5.js to do it, it's quite simple to use.

Comment: how does the index.html works? does it have to be connected to an arduino, can I use a pre-recorded file and pass the data to the correct variable?

Comment: The arduino is an ESP8266 and the files are stored into the flash memory and we access to it using the SPIFFS (LittleFS). Our ESP8266 act as a webserver that return our files.
Requests are made using the setintervall method in JS.So you should remove it to replace with you variables.

Answer (score 1):

Visualizing simple movements like this can be easily done using canvas or SVG (or even directly manipulate the position of the car image element will do the job). But you will still need a simple physics engine that can be easily written by your self. A good place to start start will be to see the car as a particle that moves along the Y axis. It has position, acceleration and velocity properties. Each frame these properties are updated and the new position of the car is rendered on the canvas(or SVG or position of the image element).

If you want to use the canvas approach, check out the [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) library, for a SVG approach, checkout [d3.js](https://d3js.org/), and I believe this can probably be done with a animated graph using [EChars](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html). And for how to construct a simple particle system, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcdigVaIYAk). Good luck coding.